# Uppercase mysql tables not working after MAMP 3 update

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

After MAMP 3 update, I can't edit or view any mysql tables with uppercase letters. On phpMyAdmin, tables has listed, but when I click on the table, I received error:

`#1146 - Table xxx.xxx doesn't exist`.

Comment: mysql db/table names are case-sensitive on OSes were the file system is case sensitive.

Comment: might be a caching issue in phpMyAdmin too?...

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem right now.
This seems to be a bug, because with `lower_case_table_names=2`, which is default for MacOS, mysql should convert table names to lowercase on comparison.

But as Mike Brant pointed out: Always use lowercase letters, to avoid those problems!

For a quick workaround to lowercase the tables, I added a file `my.cnf` to the `conf` folder:

```
/Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf
```

added following content:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=0
```

and restarted the server.

You should only use this to rename the tables. After you renamed the tables in mysql (e.g. via phpMyAdmin) and in your code, remove this file and restart again.

For more info, check out the link Mike Brant provided:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

For consistency sake, one should almost NEVER use uppercase letters in naming database objects (db's, tables, fields, etc.). Table case sensitivity is determined by the platform on which MySQL is run as well as the setting for `lower_case_table_names` server variable.

For more info, read the MySQL documentation here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Ok, but how I set `lower_case_table_names` on MAMP?

Comment: @Sam If you you name your DB objects with lowercase letters, you do not ever need to change the `lower_case_table_name` values on any system, it will just work.  The link I provided tells you how to set the variable and gives considerations on how to change table name for your system when attempting to change the variable.